# Handling exponent when converting Excel formula to JS

Tags: javascript, excel, pow

I've got this Excel formula:

```
(Assets*(1+Interest)^(CURRENT{age}+1‐Enrollment{age}))+(Salary*Employee{contribution}+Employer{contribution}))*((1+Interest)^(CURRENT{age}+1‐Enrollment{age})‐(1+Inflation)^(CURRENT{age}+1‐Enrollment{age}))/(Interest‐Inflation)
```

Which I've tried to convert into a JS formula below:

```
age_assets = (assets*Math.pow(1+interest,age+1-enroll_age))+(salary*(your_contrib+employ_contrib))*(Math.pow(1+interest, age+1-enroll_age)-Math.pow(1+inflation, age+1-enroll_age))/(interest-inflation);
```

Given these values:

```
// Age
           64,
// Retirement age
           67,
// Enrollment age
           30,
// Assets
           10000,
// Interest
           .3,
// Salary
           100000,
// Your contribution
           .10,
// Employer contribution
           .03,
// Inflation
           .02,
// Retirement type
           .85
```

The spreadsheet comes up with a far smaller value. Does anyone see any inconsistencies between the two formulas? I've never had to do this kind of thing before.

Comment: Hmmm. Should it not be `salary*your_contrib+employ_contrib`? Would not the order of operations in Excel be like that? `Salary*Employee{contribution}` then add `Employer{contribution}` to it? I may be wrong.

Comment: You may be right, but it still returns something like 578 million with that fix. Do you see any other mistakes like that? I'm terrible at math, coding is fun until I get to the actual programming parts.

Comment: With the data you provided, what is the expected answer? I am trying to re-write it.

Comment: I don't have the actual spreadsheet, which makes this a lot harder. I just have a screenshot at this point, which says the correct asset number for age 64 is 4,522,688.

Comment: Funny. When I created the JS function I got 3.3934E+12, same with Excel. I also noticed that the Retirement Type is not being used at all. Also, there is one missing parenthesis in the excel formula. I think you may have the wrong one? Or missing something?